# Binding android hardware key (back Button) to javascript method in WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Is there a way to bind the hardware back button to javascript method without using Phonecap/Cordova just in simplest android `WebView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override what happens when pressing the back button by overriding [`onBackPressed`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()). You then just have to call your javascript code in the webview with [this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)).